# Voltage divider network 12V / 24V option to UVLO pin of LED driver

Tags: ground, voltage-divider

I have a voltage divider network with R1 and R2 and another R2 in parellel but not connected to ground. I have a dip switch where turning it on changes to 24V so it adds the second R2 to ground.

Can it go directly to ground from the dip switch or does it need to go the point where the first R2 touches ground?

Data sheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3409hv.pdf?ts=1711706917437&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.it%252F
[image][image]

Comment: Now that you have replaced the earlier images with new schematics, all the previous comments were then obsolete so I have removed them. The text and images now match, so I have reopened the question.